# Is Azure DevOps hosted agent a docker container?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent

The azure agent is usually used as follows, it is named as pool and with a VM image title

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
```

Can a hosted agent in azure DevOps service be considered as a container in VM managed by azure DevOps service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a hosted agent in azure DevOps service be considered as a
>   container in VM managed by azure DevOps service?

Restrictly to say, **no**, you can not.

The key words of `vmImage` not point to a container, it just an image of a virtual machine,  a copy of the VM. This copy contain an OS, data files, and some built-in applications we pre-configured to facilitate user use.

If you want to do some [Container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) along with Hosted agents, here the suggestion of Eldho is available. Note: As of today, the container jobs only support YAML pipeline.

Or, you can get our containerized agents image from [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-pipelines-vsts-agent). But this is a self agent type.

Answer (score 2):

**Your Yaml will be run on VM**

Azure pipelines can run in VM or container. 
Each time you run a Azure pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. Microsoft-hosted agents can run jobs directly on the VM or in a container.

**A container Yaml**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

container: ubuntu:16.04

steps:
- script: printenv
```

This tells the system to fetch the ubuntu image tagged 16.04 from Docker Hub and then start the container. When the printenv command runs, it will happen inside the ubuntu:16.04 container.